# Memory Game Help! How to show the unpaired cards

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Showing the paired cards on my memory game is working fine. But the problem is I can't show the unpaired cards. There are 20 cards on my game.

```
Dim paircount As Integer = 0
Dim unpaircount As Integer

Dim Card1 As Integer = 0
Dim Card2 As Integer = 0
Dim Card1pic As Integer = 0
Dim Card2pic As Integer = 0
Dim Score As Integer = 0
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    st = st + 1
    Label3.Text = "Time : " & st & " seconds"
    Label7.Text = "Pairs : " & paircount
    If paircount = 19 And Card1 <> 0 And Card2 <> 0 Then
        paircount = paircount + 1
        victory()
        Label32.Text = "Unpaired : 20" & unpaircount    'This is my code for showing the unpaired card & and it's not working
        If unpaircount = 19 And Card1 = 0 And Card2 = 0 Then 
            unpaircount = unpaircount - paircount
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Where are you modifying `unpaircount`? Your code doesn't even show where it's declared. HOW is it not working? Is it giving the wrong count? Or is it just blank? Does the label show up at all? Need more details.

Comment: Nothing is happening to my code it just blank. Paired cards will be subtracted to the Unpaired cards.

Comment: Does the label at least display: "Unpaired : 20"? Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger to see what the value of `unpaircount` is? Have you checked to see if your `If` statement is getting entered?

Answer (score 0):

```
'[Begin]Declare Object/Value'
Dim paircount As Integer = 0
Dim unpaircount As Integer
Dim Card1 As Integer = 0
Dim Card2 As Integer = 0
Dim Card1pic As Integer = 0
Dim Card2pic As Integer = 0
Dim Score As Integer = 0
'[End]Declare Object/Value'

'[Begin]Tick handles'
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    st = st + 1
    Label3.Text = "Time : " & st & " seconds" ' Default As 1, in your code'
    Label7.Text = "Pairs : " & paircount ' Default As 0, in your code'
    If paircount = 19 And Card1 <> 0 And Card2 <> 0 Then ' Card1 & 2 default as 0, return False'
        paircount = paircount + 1 ' paircount is 20
        victory() ' your function or sub'

        Label32.Text = "Unpaired : 20" & unpaircount 'Default as null, return 0: Unpaired: 200'

        If unpaircount = 19 And Card1 = 0 And Card2 = 0 Then 'unpaircount = 0, will not be active this checking, please make sure your code will change the unpaircount value before this checking'
            unpaircount = unpaircount - paircount
        End If
    End If
End Sub
'[End]Tick handles'
```

As your code provide by yourself, for first of the checking under
'**If paircount = 19 And Card1 <> 0 And Card2 <> 0 Then**'
Is any way to change paircound/card1/card2?
If not, that mean the checking will not be accept and for my view, 
I think your code was successful display the result: no change, no display

Best Regards,
KT